# Super zoom lens vs Nikon Coolpix P1000

Tags: lens, nikon, coolpix

I know the question is not well posed, but I was thinking for shooting the moon, distant wildlife, and macro photography can I compare the following setups?

1. Nikon D810 + 70-200mm f/4G VR
2. Nikon CoolPix P1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare these cameras so sample, because:

- first have maximum focal length of 200mm, seconds - 3000mm which mean you can fill the frame with much more distant objects (with the second)
- Because of above you may have problem handheld steady the second camera for long focal lengths. But it may win when talk about the Moon
- first camera have much bigger sensor cells which mean in low light (usual situation with wildlife) will give you much less noise
- first camera cost around 2000$, second ~1000$
- none of them (as described) is good for macro photos